# What happens when a list is passed as a default parameter in a function in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, static, default

I'm not able to understand the mechanism behind this behavior in python.

```
def fun(s=[]):
   s.append(1)
   print s

fun()
fun()
```

Output is:

```
[1]
[1,1]
```

Why does python "remember" the value of the list passed on the function?

Comment: `Actually, this is not a design flaw, and it is not because of internals, or performance.
It comes simply from the fact that functions in Python are first-class objects, and not only a piece of code.`

Comment: This is explained here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments